# Next-Auth Middleware matcher regex

Tags: regex, next-auth

In the [next-auth middleware scenario](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#nextjs-middleware), you can use a matcher to enforce auth on certain paths. Here is an example of a matcher regex that forces auth on all routes *except* `/register` and `/login`:

```js
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!register|login).*)"],
};
```

I would like to allow the root page (at `/`) to be added to this list, but do not know how to do so using the RegExp syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `$` as another alternative to the positive lookahead:

```
/                     # Literal '/', followed by
(?!register|login|$)  # something that is neither 'register', 'login' nor the end of string.
```

This matches:

```
/foobar
```

But not:

```
/register
/login
/
/register-foobar
/loginbarfoo
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nAcnSP/1).

To be extra-safe, you can use this:

```
/                     # Literal '/', followed by 
(?!                   # something that is neither
  (?:register|login)? # 'register', nor 'login', optionally
  $                   # right before the end of string.
)                     #
```

This matches:

```
/foobar
/register-foobar
/loginbarfoo
```

But not:

```
/register
/login
/
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nAcnSP/2).

Comment: Absolute sorcery. Thank you, @InSync!